# Как поставить проверку инпута на submit?

Tags: html, input

Есть такой код:

```
<input pattern="\+375 \(\d{2}\) \d{3}-\d{2}-\d{2}" >
<button>Отправить</button>
```

Все работает, только если, к примеру, человек ввел 2 цифры, потом нажал отправить - ему появляется надпись:

> «Не правильно ввел».

И когда он пишет это -  надпись не исчезает пока не отправишь. Решение: сделать эту проверку только при клике на button. Как перенести проверку этого паттерна на кнопку используя JS?

Comment: Что именно не получается?

Comment: Делается это так, на кнопку вешается обработчик, который берёт из документа необходимый input и по регулярному выражению проверяет его работу. Если всё хорошо, форму отправляем, если нет, то показываем сообщение об ошибке. Сообщение об ошибке это просто скрытый div, при ошибке показываем его.